# PHP - Dynamic FORM > MySQL Insert

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here and I have one question.
I have one PHP-HTML Dynamic Form with this code:

```
  <form class="insert"  method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?CategoryName=<?php echo $CategoryName; ?>">
  <br/><label><?php echo $lang['CATEGORY_NAME']; ?>:</label>
  <?php
   $conn = new mysqli($SERVERNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Greska: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
      $sql = "SELECT CategoryName FROM Categories WHERE ForUser = '$User_Check' ";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<select style='text-transform: uppercase;' onchange='location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;' class='form-control' name='CategoryName'>";
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option value='?CategoryName=".$row['CategoryName']."'>".$row['CategoryName']."</option>";
      }
          echo "</select>";
  }         
  else {
      echo "<div style='margin-top: 18px;' class='alert alert-danger'><b>$lang[MANAGE_CATEGORY_ALERT]</b></div>";
  }
  $conn->close();
  ?>
  <?php
   $conn = new mysqli($SERVERNAME, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME);
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Greska: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 
      $sql = "SELECT FieldName FROM Fields WHERE ForUser = '$User_Check' AND ForCategory = '$CategoryName' ";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<label>".$row['FieldName'].":</label>";
          echo "<input class='form-control' id='focusedInput' required type='text' placeholder='".$row['FieldName']."' name='".$row['FieldName']."'>";
      }
  }         
  else {
      echo "<div style='margin-top: 18px;' class='alert alert-danger'><b>$lang[MANAGE_CATEGORY_ALERT]</b></div>";
  }
  $conn->close();
  ?>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['CREATE_CATEGORY_BUTTON']; ?>">
</form>
```

Now I have problem when I want to insert posted data into MySQL tables because PHP don't know where to insert posted data, and doesn't know where to enter which data.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask! There are literally _millions_ of examples out there about how to insert data into a database by means of php. Please take a look at them or, even better, read some "getting started tutorial". Then, when you have a _specific_ issue with your code you cannot solve, then is the time to ask here.

Comment: I know how to insert data into MySQL, but in this case I dont know how to get name of fields where to insert, and vaues of that fields because names of Inputs in HTML form always diffrent because they depends on the names of the fields where data will be inserted. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking @MiljanIlic

Comment: Well, that certainly is a very strange architecture you are trying to implement there. But anyways, there certainly is nothing where we can help here, is there? How should we know which input value should be stored into which table column? Maybe you should try to explain _what_ you are trying to do, not _how_ you try to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not much clear but as i can understand from the code 
you have 2 tables, categories and fields . and you are rendering the form using it . when u will submit the form, u will get all the fields and 'CategoryName' which you can fetch using a $_POST variable .

I dont know in which table u want to save the data but u can easily save it like any other form .

more over u can  open once in browser and save the generated file for debugging saving process so that u don't need to render again. 
u can always var_dump $_POST to check the data u receive after submitting form.